# Wordpress and GoDaddy Windows server - Very slow

Tags: wordpress, hosting, windows-server-2008

For a client I have to release a Wordpress website to his goDaddy Windows Server. The problem: The website is really really slow now! Almost two minutes to open a site:

[image]

On my own server it was very fast...but it´s a linux server... and sometimes I get a 500 error....

What can be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

GoDaddy Windows Server is not optimized to host a WordPress website. The last time I checked, the PHP version on a Plesk server there was still PHP 5, that is a lot slower than PHP 7.

Besides that, I wouldn't recommend running WordPress on a IIS environment. It's just not made for it and it is probably what is causing the error 500 you're getting. You might be having problems with the plugins or with your theme as well running on an old version of PHP.

Unfortunately the best option is switching the server for one optmized to host a WP website.

Comment: Thanks, but the server already has PHP 7.3.... so that´s not a PHP issue...